# Heads up push notification not doing the Pop up function

Tags: java, android, android-studio, push-notification

I am new to Android and I have been trying to show a Heads up action push notification just like whatsapp does.

This is my configuration for my notification:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, ADMIN_CHANNEL)
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher_foreground))
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.m_icon)
                        .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
                        .setTicker(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
                        .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.mblue))
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()))
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                        .setContentIntent(likePendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());
```

I have read in some post that the key to acomplish this is to set high priority to the notification but, It is still not working for me.

Comment: Are you testing on a device running Oreo or later?

Comment: Yes, it's a moto g5 plus with one pixel ROM.  Android 8.0. It's a rooted phone

Comment: Have you checked the app's notification settings? Check to see whether certain aspects that you want to display are enabled.

Comment: @LuisAguilar you set a notification channel name in the Builder's constructor, but are you actually creating that channel? If not, Android will just use some default (probably medium) priority for your notification.

Comment: @Ishaan I have not but my notifications from WhatsApp pop up correctly

Comment: Try changing the notification settings in that case. Also try what the Wanderer mentioned about creating and setting the notifications channel.

Comment: @TheWanderer I will check that thanks

Answer (score 2):

For Android Pie (9) on the emulator, I setup my channel with "IMPORTANCE_HIGH", and also set my builder priority to "PRIORITY_HIGH".

But, I still could not get heads-up notifications!

Finally, on the Android 9 emulator, I had to:

1. swipe down the notifications drawer
2. tap on "Manage Notifications"
3. select my app
4. select my channel
5. select "Behavior"
6. enable "Make sound and pop on screen".

Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that we have to add a new channel configuration whenever the OS is Oroe. So I had to validate if the OS is Oreo and then asign a channel to my notificationManager:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    setupChannels();
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void setupChannels(){
    CharSequence adminChannelName ="Global channel";
    String adminChannelDescription = "Notifications sent from the app admin";
    NotificationChannel adminChannel;
    adminChannel = new NotificationChannel(ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID, adminChannelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    adminChannel.setDescription(adminChannelDescription);
    adminChannel.enableLights(true);
    adminChannel.setImportance(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    adminChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
    adminChannel.enableVibration(true);
    if (notificationManager != null) {
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(adminChannel);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Add This Line In Your Notification Channel Builder:-

channel.setShowBadge(true)